# What is the alternative for the deprecated Notification class in the image?

Tags: android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

[image]

I intend to display my notifications in my status bar notification in android devices.
  I'm following this tutorial that is for 1 year ago.
   http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/#comment-28784 
  .It actually works fine, but the java code doesn't look like good. It should be modified even it works fine.

In this case what would be the alternative class for Notification class and how can I modify my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
Notification notification = null;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, PdfDialogAlert.class);
intent.putExtra("dialog", 1);
PendingIntent piDismiss =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

builder.setContentIntent(piDismiss)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle("fileName")
    .setTicker(message)
    .setContentText("message");

notification = builder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your brilliant answer. Now I have only one more problem that is how to remove the notification from status bar when it's clicked?  I actually added this code "mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);" but doesn't work.

Comment: In above code FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL will do that see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Comment: Hi, I have a bug in my code. Whenever we create a new user account we should always run our application from eclipse twice to be abale to display the notifications. Do you have any idea about this problem?